# How can I use fromJson to List inside Map?

Tags: dart, flutter

Usually, I will use this code to make to list.

```
jsonMap.map((gallery) => new Gallery.fromJson(gallery)).toList();
```

But I don't know how to use with a fromJson.

[This is a picture of my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qpbt.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by using.

```
List.castFrom(json['galleries']).map((gallery) => new Gallery.fromJson(gallery)).toList();
```